# Frame for clip view will be different at runtime error in Xcode 5 and Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm now building on OS X app using Xcode 5.0 and Cocoa, and when I used a lot of objects ranging from text field, text view, radio buttons, to check box, etc... and ran the simulator, it looks like working successfully. However, there are two warnings which are tagged with yellow triangles that read `Misplaced view - Frame for "clip view" will be different at runtime` in `MainMenu.xib` file.

What does the error mean? And how can I resolve the warnings? And finally, should I bother to work a bit harder to try to remove those warnings when I get to sell the app? (or does Apple still allow developers to sell an app even when it has some warnings but nonetheless sounds working?)

For your information, I didn't write any code in any of my files yet - just dragged objects out to Interface Builder, and edited and aligned those objects a bit and just ran it, which [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ACC69JC) does (but this book assumes to use Xcode 4).

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xcode5 defaults to using Auto-Layout. The warnings mean that some of your UI elements do not have enough constraints set, so when you manipulate the UI (for example resize the window) things may look different than you intended.

When you open `MainMenu.xib` in Interface Builder, a yellow arrow should appear in the component section. Click that arrow and a view appears that explains the offending elements. Each has another yellow element that brings up a context menu with suggested fixes.

Answer (score 4):

Optionally you can disable "Use Autolayout" of the nib.

Comment: be careful of that one in storyboards. i disabled autolayout in one view and it disabled the whole lot of them