# NSScrollView embedded content is hidden

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, nsscrollview

I've started learning Cocoa app development, and this simple problem is bugging me for hours, I'm sure it's something simple.

Problem:

I create a new OS X project. I drag NSScrollView on the window, then I drag a simple button within the scroll view.

When I run the program the button ( or any other content ) is hidden.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created my own project and followed exactly the same steps you did, and I too got the same result.

My project navigator contained one warning regarding a "Misplaced View":

> **Misplaced View**: Frame for "Clip View" will be different at run time.
>
> Size will be (0, 0) at run time but is (181, 94) in the canvas.

[Further research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19299725/269970) indicates this is an issue with the new auto-layout functions Apple is pushing:

> Xcode5 defaults to using Auto-Layout. The warnings mean that some of
>   your UI elements do not have enough constraints set, so when you
>   manipulate the UI (for example resize the window) things may look
>   different than you intended.
>
> When you open `MainMenu.xib` in Interface Builder, a yellow arrow
>   should appear in the component section. Click that arrow and a view
>   appears that explains the offending elements. Each has another yellow
>   element that brings up a context menu with suggested fixes.

I used a slightly different approach to correct the error: I used the menu option `Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Add Missing Constraints in Window`. The warning disappeared and the final product built exactly to the visual spec laid out in Interface Builder.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks!